# Carousel view for ipad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, carousel

[image](sony pictures app)

I need to implement carousel view for my ipad.I am searching through this forum and some websites.Many of them post coverflow view.If anybody implements carousel view please guides me..

Comment: I suppose you are looking forward to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243614/3d-carousel-effect-on-the-ipad). Go through both the answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/icarousel. It's designed for iPhone and iPad.